# Mathematical operation returns 0

Tags: c#

I can not understand why this operation is giving return of 0 to me.
Can someone help me out, have not used c# in a while, maybe something changed and it cannot be done like this anymore?

```
long temp = 18801010019;
long A = getFirstDigit(temp); // This returns the first digit of whole number
long B = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 9) % 10);
long C = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 8) % 10);
long D = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 7) % 10);
long E = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 6) % 10);
long F = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 5) % 10);
long G = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 4) % 10);
long H = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 3) % 10);
long I = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 2) % 10);
long J = (temp / (int)Math.Pow(10, 1) % 10);
long S = (A * 1) + (B * 2) + (C * 3) + (D * 4) + (E * 5) + (F * 6) + (G * 7) + (H * 8) + (I * 9) + (J * 1);
```

Comment: what does the debugger tell you?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue. Is this a function that is supposed to return S? When I run it, the value of S returned is 54.

Comment: @Arch2k probably his `getFirstDigit(temp)` is broken... as it's the function missing in this question...

Comment: Yeah, I wrote my own function to match. Hard to imagine it would return 0 though, though it could be a coincidence.

Comment: If first digit of temp is 1 then S = 54.

Comment: @Arch2K yeah, and if A=0, then the answer would be 53... The code is incomplete... where does he find the 0? Conclusion: flag post for incompleteness

Comment: I use break points in visual studio to check the values and S is still shown as 0

Comment: It does show at the end that + that it should be 54, but it is not set as that

Comment: Okay issue fixed it self after i restarted Visual studio.

Comment: instead of `Math.Pow(10, 9)` just use `1e9`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incomplete and it's not correct.
I think you want to add all the digits with an increasing multiplier. You can consider using a loop.
**edit: added Linq solution:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace MathReturns0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var temp = 18801010019;
            var A = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 10)) % 10);
            var B = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 9)) % 10);
            var C = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 8)) % 10);
            var D = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 7)) % 10);
            var E = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 6)) % 10);
            var F = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 5)) % 10);
            var G = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 4)) % 10);
            var H = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 3)) % 10);
            var I = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 2)) % 10);
            var J = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 1)) % 10);
            var K = (temp / (long)(Math.Pow(10, 0)) % 10);
            var S = (A * 1) + (B * 2) + (C * 3) + (D * 4) + (E * 5) + (F * 6) + (G * 7) + (H * 8) + (I * 9) + (J * 10) + (K * 11);

            Console.WriteLine("S has the value {0}.", S);

            Console.WriteLine("AddDigits has the value {0}.", AddDigits(temp));

            Console.WriteLine("AddDigits has the value {0}.", AddDigits2(temp));
        }

        static int AddDigits(long val)
        {
            var multiplier = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(val)));
            var output = 0;
            while (val > 0)
            {
                output += multiplier * Convert.ToInt32(val % 10);
                multiplier--;
                val /= 10;
            }
            return output;
        }

        static int AddDigits2(long val)
        {
            return val.ToString().ToList().Select((x, i) => int.Parse(x.ToString()) * (i+1)).Sum();
        }

    }
}
```

This is just quick code for a non-native C# writer. There are probably more elegant solutions